# vaadin 7: Widgetset does not contain implementation of my custom widget

Tags: java, gwt, widget, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using vaadin 7.5.6 to create a custom GWT widget and use it in my application, but when I run it, my custom component is not shown and I get the message "Widgetset does not contain an implementation for ...".

I know there are several questions related to the same issue but I've already tried all the "solutions" like:

- Re-compile the widgetset
- Clear all caches from Ivy
- Clean the project
- Check the annotation @VaadinServletConfiguration, which already contains widgetset = "com.example.myapp.widgetset.MyAppWidgetset")

But nothing works... Any suggestions of what might be the problem?

To create the widget I followed the instructions given in [Vaadin's Wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20component).

My widgetset looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!--
 Uncomment the following to compile the widgetset for one browser only.

 Multiple browsers can be specified as a comma separated list. The
 supported user agents at the moment of writing were:
 ie8,ie9,gecko1_8,safari,opera

 The value gecko1_8 is used for Firefox and safari is used for webkit
 based browsers including Google Chrome.
-->
<!-- <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/> -->

<!--
 To enable SuperDevMode, uncomment this line.

 See https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20SuperDevMode for more
 information and instructions.
-->
<!-- <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" /> -->


<inherits name="com.lexaden.business.chart.widgetset.OrganisationWidgetset" />

<inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.touchkit.gwt.TouchKitWidgetSet" />

<inherits name="org.vaadin.alump.beforeunload.gwt.BeforeUnloadWidgetSet" />

<inherits name="com.example.fieldcustomcomponents.FieldcustomcomponentsWidgetset" />
```

Thanks in advance,
Matías

Comment: I got similar error messages when I tried to add an Add-on. As far as I notice, custom widgets require *gwt.xml file and some generated files (js, etc.). Those javascript files are generating during widgetset compilation, but in my project a folder with generated widgetset land in 'target' directory instead of webapp/VAADIN/themes/. Simple copy-paste helped a lot. Maybe I misunderstood something, but please make sure that your webapp/VAADIN/themes folder has all required items.

Comment: I created another widget from scratch (a VCssLayout containing s a gwt label and a gwt button) and it worked with no problems until I added the image-upload addon to my project (I want to do a button that when is clicked it allows the user to take a picture from the mobile's camera). To add this addon I had to include the GWT file library. Any ideas now of what is going on?